# Xcode: how to create a segue from a navigation item to a new view controller?

Tags: xcode, segue

Maybe a silly question. But I've added a navigation item in code in my view controller:

```
//Set add transactions button
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addButtonAction:)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];

-(void)addButtonAction
{

}
```

And I want to segue from this navigation item directly to a new view controller. However I cannot create any segue from the previous view controller to the next one. And since my navigation item is created in code I cannot "pull" a segue from there to a new VC. How can I do that?

Comment: i think you problem is to show the `newVC`. for that you can use `pushViewController:animated:` in your `addButtonnAction`..

Comment: and how to segue back then? I mean how should I get the back button as usual in the navigation controller?

Comment: set custom back button for navigationBar and in selector method just use 'popViewController:animated:' method.

Comment: As per my knowledge back button will automatically appear as you push the view on navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
-(void)addButtonAction
{
    MyNewViewController *myNewVC = [[MyNewViewController alloc] init];

    // do any setup you need for myNewVC
    //If you want to present modal
    [self presentModalViewController:myNewVC animated:YES]; 
    //If you want to push
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myNewVC animated:YES];
}
```

Add button to dismiss if presented using modal. In case of push it will have back button